# Realistic rigid body falling physics

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

In real life, some parts of an object are heavier than others, causing the object to rotate while falling or move slightly. But in Blender, it just falls perpendicularly till it reaches a surface. Is there a way to make an object fall in a more realistic way in Blender?

Comment: first of all you should lower your expectations. Blender is a graphic (!) software, not a real world simulation software. But...as usual, you can fake it. With forces. By interacting with other objects. By manual animation...and so on. And don't forget: Blender works in a "perfect" environment. There is no wind, no friction when objects are falling. So i am not totally sure if objects would rotate "automatically" in such an environment. At least a perfect cube falling just down wouldn't ;) Maybe you should improve your question and tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the rotation with an invisible object, like this:

[image]

Comment: i can't see the invisible object in your animation... :D

Comment: Maybe one day you'll see it young padawan

Comment: @Chris wouldn't quite be invisible if you could see it now, would it? ;)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: depends on your vision capacities ‍♂️

Comment: Lol. thanks guys that's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

In real life, falling objects don't rotate much. It is a common misconception that heavier are more affected by gravity. But really, all objects (or all parts of objects, in this case) experience the exact same gravitational force no matter how much they weigh.

Occasionally, for objects that are light enough air resistance matters a lot, or fall long enough small changes have a large effect, or fall so fast air resistance is the main limiter of their speed, air resistance may cause some rotation. This is because air resistance disproportionally affects light objects and objects with greater area or speed.

In these cases, blender would be missing some rotation that occurs in real life, since blender doesn't simulate air resistance.

But these are unusual scenarios. Once you look at more normal objects, like a pen or a ball, air resistance becomes negligible and no rotation occurs.

There may sometimes be a spin on falling objects if you drop them imperfectly by hand, and accidentally spin them as you are dropping them. And objects that fall off a ledge rotate because the side still in contact with the ledge is pushed up by it. Most of the time, if you see an object spinning as it falls, one of those two reasons is why.

If you want to simulate that sort of effect, as if your object was dropped by hand or rolled off something, you can add it in manually, as others have said.

Comment: Galileo used balls for a reason, which is a strawman in the context of OP presenting a cube  A heavy object will rotate rapidly to minimize drag, as well as buoyancy will cause it to try to lower its center of mass (a box will fall with empty part pointing up even if contents aren't lose to fall within the box). While for some objects those effects are more prominent than for others, they happen always, not occasionally. And even though those effects can be very subtle, the simplest rigid body setup immediately breaks immersion for completely missing them.

Comment: Typically adding some noise is enough to get rid of the "uncanny valley"-like feeling, even though it doesn't simulate those phenomena, just like adding noise to a human movement masks well the artificial robotic animation lacking inefficiency of muscle twitching.